# how to pad numpy array while repeating values with center

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, padding

Suppose I have a numpy array that looks like this

```py
[[0 1]
 [2 3]]
```

How do I pad the values from the centers to produce a one like

```py
[[0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 3 3 3]
 [2 2 2 3 3 3]
 [2 2 2 3 3 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

`np.pad` is your friend here. The `mode=edge` argument makes sure that the padded values are taken from the closest element in the original array:

```
np.pad([[0, 1], [2, 3]], 2, mode='edge')
>>> array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
           [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
           [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
           [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
           [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
           [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: thanks, this worked like a charm

Comment: The above fails when having higher dimension. The method only accounts for edges

Comment: It should work in higher dimensions no problem, eg. ```np.pad(np.arange(8).reshape(2,2,2), 2, mode='edge')```